# Python. Anaconda Prompt. Комманда "jupyter notebook" не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, anaconda, запуск

Начала делать как в инструкции чтобы запустить "Anaconda Prompt" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mDYijMfSzs

Windows 10 64 bit

были выполнены комманды от имени Администратора в [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

python --version

[image: python --version]

conda info

[image: conda info]

conda install numpy

[image: conda install numpy]

jupyter notebook

[image: jupyter notebook]

После "jupyter notebook"

Comment: Anaconda promt у вас как раз работает. у вас не запускается ноутбук. Уточните свой вопрос.

Comment: Стоп. Юпитер запускается с ярлыка, который лежит в "пуске -> анаконда".